# Import Logger in Swift Package gives error when building for iOS only

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I created a new Swift Package and added this to the Package.swift:

```
platforms: [
    .iOS(.v14)
],
```

In the source file, I added this code:

```
import OSLog
let log = Logger()
```

Now I get this error:

> 'Logger' is only available in in macOS 11.0 or newer

That is strange, since it should also be available on iOS 14>: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logger

How can I solve this error while NOT adding macOS to the platforms? I don't want to build for macOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your framework pointing to `My Mac` by chance? Try changing it to an iPhone.

[image: Build destination]

Comment: Just leaving it there for those passing by, as well as `My Mac` is not `My Mac (Mac Catalyst).